# Retaining a hover state while outside the viewport

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I have an absolutely positioned `<div>` (basically a menu) in the corner of a page that animates on hover. However, when the cursor moves beyond the viewport the hover action ends. I want the menu to retain the hover state while the cursor is off the page.

For example:

```html
                               Retain hover while
|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾| outside viewport
| Viewport           | hover |
|                    | state |
|                    |_______|
|                            |
|                            |
```

I have a Stackblitz snippet that is a better example of the behavior: https://stackblitz.com/edit/outside-viewport?file=index.html

Though my Stackblitz example uses CSS, I do not care if the solution uses JavaScript instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use javascript to add a class to show it in the "*hovered*" state, and then monitor the `mouseOver` event of the window, and test if the event comes from outside the `#menu` in order to shrink it back.

```js
(function(){
  let menuIsActive = false;
  const menuElement = document.querySelector('#menu');

  const mouseEnter = () => {
     menuElement.classList.add('active')
     window.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverWindow);
  }
  const mouseOverWindow = (e) => {
    if (!e.target.closest('#menu')){
      menuElement.classList.remove('active');
      window.removeEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverWindow)
    }
  }

  menuElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseEnter)
})();
```

```css
#content, h4 {
  max-width: 70%;
}

#menu {
  background-color: red;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 12%;
  width: 15%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
#menu.active{
  background-color: purple;
  height: 40%;
  width: 22%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h4>The red box should retain the hover state while the cursor is beyond the viewport</h4>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

<div id="menu"></div>
```

Demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/outside-viewport-d2swrb?file=index.js

Comment: This is great solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the `mouseover` and pass the class instead of applying the styles on hover. Something like this.

```
    let currentState = document.getElementById("menu");
    currentState.addEventListener("mouseover", func, false);

    function func() { 
      currentState.classList.add("menuExpand");
    }
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnxckt95/)**

you will have to use the `mouseout` to shrink the menu back. But not knowing your requirement after the menu is expanded, the above will only keep it expanded.